# Multiple formulas need simplifying

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet file with multiple pages in it. One called inputs which as 60 groups of information. The columns are the same for each of the 60 groups but the values are different. From here I want to have multiple formulas that summarises the data.

For example:

I have a summary page and I want cell D5 to add the values from the inputs page with the columns with a heading of weekly for one line. My inputs page has 1050 of data. With formatting and headings there is 50 lines leaving 1000 lines of data. So those 1000 lines need to be totalled across the 60 groups.

I am open to suggestions on making it simpler.

An example of my data is like this

```
B10 = Date1
C10 = Product
D10 = W1
E10 = W2
F10 = W3
G10 = RB
I10 = W1
J10 = W2
K10 = W3
```

L10 = RB

This goes on for 60 groups and 1000 days. Therefore the summary page shows the totals for W1, W2, W3 and RB per date. I didn't want a formula that added each column I wanted to automate the calculation. My 60 groups will actually turn into 4 values for each group and then 1000 times based on date. My VLOOKUP kept returning an error so I don't know where I went wrong. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here is a link to the sheet. https://docs.google.com/file/d/1ztTi1PTZ7el8EvyOEKvqw7yBnjO8v23o/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: I have updated the settings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't have dates in B10:B27 - that's why your vlookup did not work so first step is to recreate it with:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ROW(Inputs!A9:A), 
 IF(Inputs!B9:B<>"", {ROW(Inputs!A9:A), Inputs!B9:B}), 2, 1))
```

then we need column D and range G:J as virtual array so:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({VLOOKUP(ROW(Inputs!A9:A), 
 IF(Inputs!B9:B<>"", {ROW(Inputs!A9:A), Inputs!B9:B}), 2, 1), Inputs!D9:D, Inputs!G9:J})
```

next, we sort it in reverse order:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT({VLOOKUP(ROW(Inputs!A9:A), 
 IF(Inputs!B9:B<>"", {ROW(Inputs!A9:A), Inputs!B9:B}), 2, 1), Inputs!D9:D, Inputs!G9:J}, ROW(Inputs!A9:A), 0))
```

now we can vlookup on your summary sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B5:B, SORT({VLOOKUP(ROW(Inputs!A9:A), 
 IF(Inputs!B9:B<>"", {ROW(Inputs!A9:A), Inputs!B9:B}), 2, 1), 
 Inputs!D9:D, Inputs!G9:J}, ROW(Inputs!A9:A), 0), {3,4,5,6}, 0)))
```

[image]

and from there we just bind Inputs!G9:J range to numbers on row 3 in Inputs sheet and make the range selection dynamic:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP($B$5:$B, SORT({VLOOKUP(ROW(Inputs!$A$9:$A), 
 IF(Inputs!$B$9:$B<>"", {ROW(Inputs!$A$9:$A), Inputs!$B$9:$B}), 2, 1), 
 Inputs!$D$9:$D, INDIRECT("Inputs!"&
 ADDRESS(9, H3*7-2*(H3-1), 4)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(
 ADDRESS(1, H3*10-5*(H3-1), 4), 1, ))}, ROW(Inputs!$A$9:$A), 0), {3,4,5,6}, 0)))
```

and now you just copy cell H5 and paste to M5, R5, etc

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FpkRCr-nJlBpY9e8n9WgQ288Q76xKd3W7EyMG1rn_Gs/edit#gid=1429833575)

Comment: Thank you I will give it a go and see if I can get my head around it as I have quite a large data source to calculate